# Where i should save images to use it with Fileprovider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

i have read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) about Fileprovider but i don't understand where i should put the images (or path of the images) that i want share. I understand that with xml file "file_path" i set the new path when my app share the images. I also understand that i must create a new file path and a new file for the image with this code:

`File imagePath = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");`

But i don't understand where i should put images in Android Studio, there is a specific directory ? And an extra question, with Fileprovider can i share a drawable resource ? Thanks

Comment: Strange. The documentation is very clear where to store your files. Look at the sentences starting with `Represents files in the ....`.

Comment: Sorry but i can't see the part where is it written where i should put my files stored in my pc in Android Studio (wich folder, directory ecc)

Comment: You should do a textual search with your browser. Then the browser will find. And you can see them.

Answer (score 0):

> with Fileprovider can i share a drawable resource

No. Moreover, given that drawables vary by density, it is unclear what this would even mean.

> where i should put images in Android Studio, there is a specific directory ?

`FileProvider` does not serve files from your app's APK or your project. It serves files from the filesystem of the user's device (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).

You are welcome to package a file with your app (e.g., in `assets/`), then copy it to a location that `FileProvider` will serve from.

Comment: Ok i understood what you're trying to say, but i don't know why android studio doesn't compile my assets folder. What i means is that if i try to go in the app package with my rooted phone and there isn't any assets folder and into the file folder there isn't my fileprovider path that i have declared into the xml as the documentation says (Maybe i should create the path in my java code ?). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Smart: "What i means is that if i try to go in the app package with my rooted phone and there isn't any assets folder and into the file folder there isn't my fileprovider path that i have declared into the xml as the documentation says" -- assets are entries in the APK file, and `FileProvider` does not create a directory. If you have further concerns in this area, please ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve].